# Questions related to movies or episodes not released yet

Tags: discussion, scope

How to deal with questions which are related to parts of a movie which are going to be released in the future or the suspense created by a movie/TV-series to be revealed later? Like this [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/37092/why-did-kattappa-kill-baahubali), which asks a question about an incident which is added in end of the first movie of a series, for the sole purpose of creating the  suspense. As of now, only the writers and directors know what is going to happen. Other people can only speculate which leads to opinion-based answers.

Shoud we mark them as opinion-based questions?

Comment: The answer I've gotten in the past essentially adds up to... "There's no rule that a question must be answerable **now**."

Comment: @Catija Was this on a meta question? If yes, can you link to it?

Comment: Related: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1883/49.

Comment: It's subjective aint it? Maybe on its face a question is only answerable in the future to someone not versed in it's history, but its answerable right away due to extra-canon sources like interviews or commentary. Or adaptations of other medias/reboots (Attack on Titan books inform the anime inform the live action movie)? Or something like the MCU where marvel releases canon prequel comics?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a **significant** and ***quantified*** number of unanswered questions, or questions with **significantly** and ***numerous*** low quality speculative answers without evidence, attempting to preempt "can only be answered in the future" questions seems narrow sighted. If you can't show statistics that it's a problem, don't worry about a solution yet.

Plenty of questions may only seem unanswerable or speculative to someone not well informed about that title, but they can be answered with extra-canon sources like interviews or supporting canon.